# Linear Layout shorten text in textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a status bar with 6 elements in a row in a linear layout. This looks ok on a newer display with high resolution. But when I start the app on my old smartphone only the first text of the Textview in the status bar is shown. The imageViews are cut off and the status bar gets higher without extra content.

What I want is, that if the content does not fit, the text in the first textView is shorten, so that the ImageViews can all be shown. Is this possible?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusbar_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="Text der Statusbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusbar_text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="TEXT1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_state0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_state1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_state2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_state3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to Use Relative Layout with relations or else use the LinearLayout with weightsum (Each view add weight).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add weight for all elements . If weights are equal the Layout will be divided equally. if weight is twice the others then the division will be twice.  if `orientation` is `vertical` and you had **given weight** then height should be `0dp` and if it is `horizontal` , width should be `0dp`

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusbar_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text der Statusbar" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusbar_text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="TEXT1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_state0"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_state1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_state2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/some_state3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
        android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state3" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The keyword weight gave me the right hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970401/3844302. I gave weight=1 to the TextView and the other elements get weight=0.

Comment: Happy Coding Bro :)

Answer (score 0):

you should make your `layout` like this. adding `weight` to the views will fix their `widths`. So no matter the `text length` it won't disturb your `imageViews`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="2dp"
android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusbar_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Text der Statusbar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusbar_text1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="TEXT1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/some_state0"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/some_state1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/some_state2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state2" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/some_state3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/stat_some_state3" />

</LinearLayout>
```